# Flutter email + level test Auth logic

Tags: flutter

I want to make an app where people can learn languages. I want to make two cases.

1. First, when you sign up, you sign up, enter additional information, do a level test, and go to the main page.
2. If you have registered as a member, you go to the dashboard right away whenever you turn on the app.

Please check the screenshot that I added.

Can anyone recommend me what part I should study for this or a video or a lecture?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy workflow to start with:

- Create your screens.
- On the `Sign Up` Screen, if successfully signed up, save the `Sign In`
  State(true/false)) in `Shared Preferences`.
- Check the credentials or `Sign In` State when the app starts. If
  condition satisfies, navigate to the relevant screen and if condition
  doesn't satisfy, navigate to the Sign In screen.

Find more info about Shared Preferences in [this Link](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).